# How to access parent's @last in handelbars?

Tags: handlebars.js

With handlebars templates, you can use `@last` to get the last item in an `#each`, however, I want to know the last item of a *parent's* `#each`:

Here is my template (simplified):

```
{{#each property}}
<li class="property">property-header</li>

    {{#each this.modules}}
    <li class="module">module-header</li>

        {{#each this.items}}
        <li class="{{if @last of property}}last{{/if}}">item</li>

        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Obviously `{{if @last of property}}` does not work, but it's what I want to achieve.

This is the generated output:

```
<!-- property -->
<li>property-header</li>
<li>module-header</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>module-header</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li> <!-- TARGET THIS ONE

<!-- property -->
<li>property-header</li>
<li>module-header</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li> <!-- TARGET THIS ONE

<!-- property -->
<li>property-header</li>
<li>module-header</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>module-header</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>module-header</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li> <!-- TARGET THIS ONE
```

---

It shouldn't be hard if I was able to wrap content in a span or div, but that's not possible with a list. There also no `previous sibling` selector in CSS so I also can't target the last item before a `.property-header`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are able to select the parent's `@last` with `@../last`, so:

```
<li class="{{#if @../last}}{{#if @last}}last{{/if}}{{/if}}">
    item
</li>
```